# What is the use of class attribute which is a method/function

Tags: python

In Python when we define class all its members including variables and methods also becomes attributes of that class. In following example `MyClass1.a` and `MyClass1.mydef1` are attributes of class `MyClass1`.

```
class MyClass1:
    a = 10

    def mydef1(self):
        return 0

ins1 = MyClass1()         # create instance
print(MyClass1.a)         # access class attribute which is class variable
print(MyClass1.mydef1)    # No idea what to do with it so just printing
print(ins1.mydef1)        # No idea what to do with it so just printing
```

Output

```
10
<function MyClass1.mydef1 at 0x0000000002122EA0>
<bound method MyClass1.mydef1 of <__main__.MyClass1 object at 0x000000000212D0F0>>
```

Here attribute `a` is a variable and it can be used like any other variable.
But `mydef1` is a method, if it is not invoked and just used like `MyClass1.mydef1` or `ins1.mydef1`, it returns object for that method(correct me if I am wrong).
So my question is, what can we do with the Class/instance methods without invoking it? Are there any use cases for it or is it just good to know thing?

Comment: Functions (and therefore methods) are objects in Python like anything else. That means you can pass them around, for instance as callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attribute of a class that happens to be a function becomes a method for instances or that class:

```
inst.foo(params, ...)
```

is internally translated into:

```
cls.foo(inst, params, ...)
```

That means that what is actually invoked is the attribute from the class of the instance, and the instance itself is prepended to the argument list. It is just Python syntax to invoke methods on objects.

In your example the correct uses would be:

```
print(MyClass1.mydef1(ins1))    # prints 0
print(ins1.mydef1())            # also prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instance methods can be called with the appropriate parameters of course:

```
print(ins1.mydef1()) # no parameters, so empty parenthesis, this call should print "0" in your example instead of the method description
```

If you use it without the parenthesis, you are playing with reference to the function, I don't think you can have any use of it, except checking the list of methods available in a class or something like that.